# How Can I add a PDF file on my local machine as an attachment to Teams chat using Graph API, so that everyone in the chat can access the file

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I tried the following code and it didn't worked out.

```
   Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                    String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    chatMessage = new ChatMessage
                    {
                        Body = new ItemBody
                        {
                            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                            Content ="this is test message, <attachment id=" + "someguid ID" + "></attachment>"

                        },
                        Attachments = new List<ChatMessageAttachment>()
                        {
                            new ChatMessageAttachment
                            {
                                 Id = "someguid ID",
                                 ContentType = "application/pdf",                                   
                                 Name = Path.GetFileName(x),
                                 Content = file
                            }
                        }
                    };
    await graphClient.Teams[cbTeam.SelectedValue.ToString()].Channels[cbChannel.SelectedValue.ToString()].Messages
                                   .Request()
                                   .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

The error I am getting from graph is unable to process the content

Answer (score 0):

From the [chatMessage resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) documentation, `attachments` property is currently read-only and sending attachments is not supported - which would explain the error above. Kindly consider [filing a feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so this can be looked into.

Let me know if this helps.